# Why this solution of the birthday problem is wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we have $n$ people there are $n(n-1)/2$ possible pairs that we can find. The probability that any two people have the same birthday is $1/365$. So for $n$ people the probability of finding at least one pair with the same birthday is $\frac{1}{365} \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Setting this to $50\%$ we get that $n=20$ and not $23$ as it should be. What is wrong with the solution?

Comment: Well clearly there has to be something wrong, because it's not long before it becomes larger than $1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Good point.

Comment: This approach certainly is correct when trying to count the number of edges in a random graph, $G(n,p)$ with $p=\frac{1}{365}$ and $n$ such that $E[e(G)]\geq 0.5$.  The difficulty lies in that in the birthday problem the edges themselves could not be independent whereas in a random graph they must be.  The expected number of edges in a random graph $G(n,p)$ is indeed $\binom{n}{2}p$, however as the edges in the birthday problem are not independent, we need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of pairs is $$\frac{1}{365} \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

However, this also includes cases that there are two, three, four, or even more pairs. Therefore the number is a little lower.